# HTML input escaping - what's the proper way?

Tags: java, angularjs, jackson, xss

Consider application:

JS Framework Frontend (for example AngularJS) and 
REST API Backend (for example Jackson + Spring REST) and some HTML mail templates.

what's the proper way of globally securing whole system from XSS?

First thing is securing web components on the frontend from exposing HTML entities from input fields.

Second thing is preventing backend services from creating HTML templates (for example HTML mails) which would contain malicious values from user fields.

Imagine field like post / comment which would contain Twitter style tags - #tag would be converted automatically to hyperlink pointing to someurl/tags/tag, which would be build by creating HTML tags when rendering, and then, final div would be appended to website. Other use of this kind of div would be to embed it in HTML mail template, which would be sent to other users via SMTP.

There will be various fields in application like this one.

I don't want to disallow users from entering non alphanumeric characters from those fields via regex or backend validation. However, this input will be exposed in way which would allow XSS attacks by default.

What would be proper way to secure this kind of fields? Should it be done globally, using Jackson filter / converter / escaper, when posting field value to backend? Or should it be everytime escaped, when exposing to every place in the frontend or mail templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should:

- Escape the values on the front end when they are rendered.  This should be done with a global utility or setting.  Some front end frameworks do this by default (e.g. React).
- Validate values when being submitted to the backend and prevent characters where appropriate.  E.g. A name field probably does not need `<` or `>`.

You could consider:

- Providing endpoints that return escaped values if so requested (i.e. `&escapeHtml=true`).  I'm not personally a fan of this, but maybe it is appropriate for your situation.

I don't recommend:

- Escaping all data before storing in the backend.  Maybe this is personal preference, but escaping the data for html rendering is presuming that the data will only be used for such (e.g. what happens if someone is calling the API directly for putting the data into a CSV or other format for which the html escapes do not apply).